# pgfgantt arrows look wired

Tags: pgfgantt

Here is my MEW:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}
\begin{document}
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%}
\begin{ganttchart}
    [
        vgrid,
        hgrid,
        x unit=.4mm,
        time slot format=little-endian,
        newline shortcut=true,
        bar label node/.append style = {align=right}
    ]{18-01-2020}{31-08-2020}
    \ganttbar[progress=50]{Administrative  tasks}{19-01-2020}{24-01-2020}\\\\
    
    \ganttlinkedbar{Literature study}{27-01-2020}{24-02-2020}\\\\
    
    \ganttlinkedbar{Finalize GRLS logic}{24-02-2020}{23-03-2020}
    
\end{ganttchart}}
\end{document}
```

This is how it looks like
[image]

Why is the arrows pointing in the wrong direction

Answer (score 1):

Your MWE has a **very** low `x unit` value. You'd need to adjust other spacing values for a better fit, e.g. with `link bulge=5,  link tolerance=2` (you may need to adjust these factors as you enter more data).

However, I think a better solution would be to use a coarse-grained resolution. Your MWE tries to squeeze more than half a year onto letter or A4 paper on a daily grid. Choosing a monthly grid may be more efficient for the data you have entered (unfortunately, `pgfgantt` does not offer a `weekly` resolution).

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}
\begin{document}
    \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%}
        \begin{ganttchart}
            [
            vgrid,
            hgrid,
            time slot unit=month,
            time slot format=little-endian,
            newline shortcut=true,
            bar label node/.append style = {align=right},
            bar progress label node/.append style = {xshift=.5em},
            ]{01-11-2019}{31-08-2020}
            \ganttbar[progress=50]{Administrative  tasks}{19-01-2020}{24-01-2020}\\\\

            \ganttlinkedbar{Literature study}{27-01-2020}{24-02-2020}\\\\

            \ganttlinkedbar{Finalize GRLS logic}{24-02-2020}{23-03-2020}

    \end{ganttchart}}
\end{document}
```